# convert a string date to a timezone date and then make it local - moment js

Tags: momentjs

**Context:**

I have a UTC date selector and timezone selector in my database. I want to show the date in the front end in my local time, so in the following example, in my CMS i set Paris as 10:00 for November 1st, so i should see 09:00 in London for November 1st.

**Problem:**

I've been playing with this for a few hours now.

I am in London timezone.

```
// The following is coming out of my database for an article (Note it's November, after BST or CEST):
var articleDate = "2019-11-01T10:00:00"
var timezoneDisplayName = "(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris"
```

I convert the articleDate to UTC, as it's supposed to be UTC date in database:

```
var articleDateAsUTC = moment.utc(articleDate);
```

[image]

I then add the timezone offset so that the date is now in the correct format to be converted to local time *(You can see that it says offset 60 and the date remains the same)*:

```
var articleDateAfterAddingOffset = articleDateAsUTC.utcOffset(timezoneDisplayName);
```

[image]

I then convert it to localtime (you can see it's still offset 60 and the date remains the same):

```
var convertDateToLocal = articleDateAfterAddingOffset.local();
```

[image]

And finally, i format it:

```
var formattedDate = convertDateToLocal.format(format);
```

[image]

Surely the date should be 09:00 in UK when it's 10:00 in Paris?

What am i doing wrong?

Entire code here:

```
var articleDate = "2019-11-01T10:00:00"
var timezoneDisplayName = "(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris"
var articleDateAsUTC = moment.utc(articleDate);
var articleDateAfterAddingOffset = articleDateAsUTC.utcOffset(timezoneDisplayName);
var convertDateToLocal = articleDateAfterAddingOffset.local();
var formattedDate = convertDateToLocal.format(format);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely happy with this but it looks like I've found the solution.

I had access to the windows time zone name and have used that against a timezone mapper i found which converts it to IANA.

I then used the timezone framework with moment to convert it using that.

```
//this exists to map windows timezones to IANA used by moment.js
var map = [ { "windowsName": "Romance Standard Time", "territory": "001", "iana": ["Europe/Paris"] } ];    

var foundMapping = map.filter(function(item){
    return item.windowsName == timezone.StandardName;
});

// Regions for some countries have many entries. We are just choosing the first in the array
var chosenMapping = foundMapping[0];

var momentTimezone = chosenMapping.iana[0];

var timezonedDate = moment.tz(articleDate, momentTimezone);
return timezonedDate.local().format(format);
```

You can even use this as  a data source that means you don't have to worry about the region problem in my first map:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unicode-org/cldr/master/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml